# Como implementar solicitações de intervalo de bytes w3c?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, html5-video

O vídeo reproduza certo. Porem não consigo pular o tempo de vídeo.

Exemplo: Pular tempo de 05:00 para 10:00.

Ele só fica rodando, e não consigo pular o tempo.

Pesquisei na internet e dizem que tem que fazer fluxo ou range ou buffer. Eu não entendo muito bem com isso. Link: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233

Alguns dizem para implementar solicitações de intervalo de bytes w3c. Só não sei mínina idéia onde começar.

Segue código:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public EmptyResult StreamUploadedVideo(int num)
{
    byte[] teste = null;
    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var result = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.Campo == 1).FirstOrDefault();

        teste =  result.Movie;

        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=nome.mp4");  //add header to httpcontext > response.
        HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(teste);  //write bytes to httpcontext response
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="@Url.Action("StreamUploadedVideo","Controller" })" type="video/mp4">
    <p>This browser does not support the video element.</p>
</video>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Já implementei esse bagulho aí, ajuda a diminuir a carga!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas formas básica de se fazer streaming de video via web:

- **Pseudo Streaming**: Leva esse nome pois, na verdade, ele não faz streaming, ele faz o download de todo binário do video, de forma progressiva, e vai reproduzindo de acordo com que o download vai acontecendo. Em alguns players vc podia dar *pause* no video e aguardo todo seu download acontecer, para então assistir todo o video sem *buffering*. Benefícios: É mais fácil de hospedar e de reproduzir os videos. Malefícios: É mais caro de transmitir, pois vc sempre entrega todo os conteúdo, mesmo que todo o video não seja assistido.
- **Adaptive Streaming**: Esse método, ao invés de baixar todo o binário, ele baixa apenas *chunks* - pedaços - do video, de acordo com que a reprodução do video vai acontecendo. Essa é a técnica mais usada hoje pelo YouTube, Netflix, etc. Benefícios: Mais barato de transmitir, pode-se adicionar várias qualidades - bitrates - do vídeo, tornado-os assistíveis em qualquer largura de banda. Malefícios: Mais difícil de hospedar, pois requer um servidor específico para o fim.

Usando Adaptive Streaming, por baixar apenas pedaços, pode-se solicitar para começar baixar a partir de um determinado período, ao invés de sempre reproduzir do início.

Se quiser deixar tudo mais simples, você pode usar [Azure Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/media-services/) para isso. Aqui eu fiz um treinamento sobre [como hospedar seus vídeos no Azure](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/mva-visao-geral-azure-media-services/). Talvez possa agilizar sua vida.